# Better ways to initialize property backing field once on first call

Tags: c#, optimization, interface, properties, initialization

I have interface `IDataHolder` that defines property holding some data and multiple classes that inherits that interface. Each objects can have unique data with type `DataType` which has child classes. But data needs to be generated first before accessing it.

When creating new classes using that interface I always need to generate data somewhere in the code and it became repetitive task. Right now I have two options:

```
private DataType data;
public DataType Data {get => data; set => data = value;}

public void Init()
{
    Data = GenerateData();
}
```

Or more favorable...

```
private DataType data;
public DataType Data
{
    get => data ? data : data = GenerateData();
    set => data = value;
}
```

*So the question is*:
***Is there a better way to create property that assigns backing field once on first call?***

*Full code example:*

```
public interface IDataHolder
{
    DataType Data { get; set;}
}
public class Base
    {
        public T <T>GenerateData()
        { 
            // data generation
        }
    }
public class Derived : Base, IDataHolder
    {
        private DataType data;
        public DataType Data
        {
            get => data ? data : data = GenerateData();
            set => data = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What, in your view, would be _better_?

Comment: Something even shorter and easier to read. Preferably in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Lazy<>`.

```
private Lazy<DataType> data = new Lazy<DataType>(GenerateData);

public DataType Data
{
    get => data.Value;
}
```

The first time data.Value is called, the Value will be assigned from the result of `GenerateData`, every other time, it will just return the value.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is best as it can get !